# iTextSharp: Need help to repeat some columns in the 1st row of the table after page break

Tags: itext, pdfptable

I am creating a PDF document using iTextSharp. The document is a bunch of tables. Some of the tables span over a few pages.

First column is a date. If several rows of the table has the same date in 1st column, only I output date only in the first row, the following rows have a blank column - until the date changes.

I do it by storing last column value in a variable and comparing it before adding a cell in the new row.

But if a table doesn't fit in one page I want to repeat the date column on the first row after the page break, so the user doesn't have to return to the previous page to see the date.

My table has a header and it repeats on new pages fine (I am setting PdfPTable.HeaderRows).

I tried to clear my variable that store last printed date in onStartPage and onEndPage but it didn't help.

Basically I want something like this:

(Beginning of the table)

```
=======================================================
  Date           Something related to the date        
======================================================= 
  01/01/2011     Something happened on January 1
                 Something else happened on this day
  01/05/2011     Here is another day
  01/07/2011     New day
                 Still 01/07/2011
                 Still there
```

(After page break - the table continues and the date repeats in 1st row)

```
=======================================================
  Date           Something related to the date        
======================================================= 
  01/07/2011     It is still January 7th but the date 
                 column repeats as this is a new page
                 And still the 7th
  01/15/2011     New day now
  01/17/2011     And another day
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is actually a lot harder than it seems. If you're responding to a `PdfPCellEvent` then the cell's already been written and you can't really undo that. The best way that I can think to do this is to manually calculate that table height, figure out where the table will wrap based on where its placed on the page and the page's size and fill in the blanks as necessary.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I may try this. Will it be also possible to do it in PdfTableEvent and "paint" it over a blank cell?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider grouping your list first by date before adding it to PdfTable.This can be easily achieve by using LINQ. After grouping, iterate to each group and add the date group value in the first column and then iterate through each member of the group and add them all (values related to the date) up in the second column.